# Appending a node multiple times using JavaScript only appends once

Tags: javascript, html

Why, when I run this sample code, is only one 'A node' appended to my ul list?  Do I need to create a new node each time I have to append?  Note: Using `appendNode(node.cloneNode(true))` does append many times.

```js
let node = document.createElement("LI");
let textnode = document.createTextNode("A node");
node.appendChild(textnode);
for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

Comment: You're appending the same node every time.  If you want multiple nodes, you have to use multiple `createElement`s.

Comment: or `.appendChild(node.cloneNode());` - though, not quite that simple of course ... `node.cloneNode(true)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're appending the same node each time - place all your code inside the `for` loop and it works:

```js
for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  let node = document.createElement("LI");
  let textnode = document.createTextNode("A node");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

Alternatively, use `cloneNode`:

```js
let node = document.createElement("LI");
let textnode = document.createTextNode("A node");
node.appendChild(textnode);
for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

Comment: I was curious as to why you cannot add the same node multiple times. According to docs "If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position". Docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: `node.cloneNode(node)` ??? really? you mean `node.cloneNode(true)` (same result, but more accurate, since the argument to cloneNode is `true` if you want deep clone)

Answer (score 1):

That's because your code is appending the same node to your list. In order to create and append multiple nodes, you have to make sure that

`let node = document.createElement("LI");`,
`let textnode = document.createTextNode("A node");`,
and `node.appendChild(textnode);`

are inside your `for` loop.